# Firebase analytics dashboard - User retention by cohort graph showing false "look forward" data

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

It is giving "User retention by cohort" information till 24th June 2023. Now, this metric gives a "look forward" view of day 1, day 7, and day 30. So my question is - how does it look forward 30 days from 24th June 2023?

For 24th June, it is currently giving "day 30" user retention rate as 2.4%. Even though they explicitly mention:

```
Note: this metric is a look-forward view and will only calculate if there is enough data available.
```

[image]